# Trying to automate adding create-react-app build script into a razor page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, razor, automation, create-react-app

So I have a .NET Core app using razor views and certain components within my razor pages are rendered using react. I'm trying to automate my build process using [cake](https://cakebuild.net/). So step 1 is using cake to run the create-react-app npm build and generate the react bundle.js and bundle.css.

Because these generated scripts and stylesheets have random hashes attached to them I need a way to automate injecting the generated bundle.js and bundle.css in my index.cshtml script section and style section respectively.

So something like this:

```
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <script src="~/static/js/main.xxxxxxxxx.js"></script>
</environment>
```

where x is the randomly generated hash

**Edit:** Cake is just basically a way to write automation scripts using c# so knowledge of cake is not required. I'm just looking for a way to do this using .NET and razor pages